# How do I perform a convolution in python with a variable-width Gaussian?

Tags: python, signal-processing, resolution, convolution, probability-density

I need to perform a convolution using a Gaussian, however the width of the Gaussian needs to change. I'm not doing traditional signal processing but instead I need to take my perfect Probability Density Function (PDF) and ``smear" it, based on the resolution of my equipment.

For instance, suppose my PDF starts out as a spike/delta-function. I'll model this as a very narrow Gaussian. After being run through my equipment, it will be smeared out according to some Gaussian resolution. I can calculate this using the scipy.signal convolution functions.

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt

    import scipy.signal as signal
    import scipy.stats as stats

    # Create the initial function. I model a spike
    # as an arbitrarily narrow Gaussian
    mu = 1.0 # Centroid
    sig=0.001 # Width
    original_pdf = stats.norm(mu,sig)

    x = np.linspace(0.0,2.0,1000) 
    y = original_pdf.pdf(x)
    plt.plot(x,y,label='original')


    # Create the ``smearing" function to convolve with the
    # original function.
    # I use a Gaussian, centered at 0.0 (no bias) and
    # width of 0.5
    mu_conv = 0.0 # Centroid
    sigma_conv = 0.5 # Width
    convolving_term = stats.norm(mu_conv,sigma_conv)

    xconv = np.linspace(-5,5,1000)
    yconv = convolving_term.pdf(xconv)

    convolved_pdf = signal.convolve(y/y.sum(),yconv,mode='same')

    plt.plot(x,convolved_pdf,label='convolved')
    plt.ylim(0,1.2*max(convolved_pdf))
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

This all works no problem. But now suppose my original PDF is not a spike, but some broader function. For example, a Gaussian with sigma=1.0. And now suppose my resolution actually *varys* over x: at x=0.5, the smearing function is a Gaussian with sigma_conv=0.5, but at x=1.5, the smearing function is a Gaussian with sigma_conv=1.5. And suppose I know the functional form of the x-dependence of my smearing Gaussian. Naively, I thought I would change the line above to

```
    convolving_term = stats.norm(mu_conv,lambda x: 0.2*x + 0.1)
```

But that doesn't work, because the norm function expects a value for the width, not a function. In some sense, I need my convolving function to be a 2D array, where I have a different smearing Gaussian for each point in my original PDF, which remains a 1D array.

So is there a way to do this with functions *already* defined in Python? I have some code to do this that I wrote myself....but I want to make sure I've not just re-invented the wheel.

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Comment: Your xconv "step" `(last - first) / (length - 1)` being different to x "step" makes the width scaled (i.e., the sigmas aren't in the same "unit"), you really want that?

Comment: "I have some code to do this that I wrote myself" => can you show us this code? It might be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Question, in brief:
How to convolve with a non-stationary kernel, for example, a Gaussian that changes width for different locations in the data, and does a Python an existing tool for this?

Answer, sort-of:
It's difficult to prove a negative, but I do not think that a function to perform a convolution with a non-stationary kernel exists in scipy or numpy.  Anyway, as you describe it, it can't really be vectorized well, so you may as well do a loop or write some custom C code.

One trick that might work for you is, instead of changing the kernel size with position, **stretch the data with the inverse scale** (ie, at places where you'd want to the  Gaussian with to be 0.5 the base width, stretch the data to 2x).  This way, you can do a single warping operation on the data, a standard convolution with a fixed width Gaussian, and then unwarp the data to original scale.

The advantages of this approach are that it's very easy to write, and is completely vectorized, and therefore probably fairly fast to run.

Warping the data (using, say, an interpolation method) will cause some loss of accuracy, but if you choose things so that the data is always expanded and not reduced in your initial warping operation, the losses should be minimal.