# Convolution in log space

Tags: convolution

I need to do a convolution with a given kernel. This kernel is defined in linear space (in this case: wavelength), but I need to do the convolution in logarithmic space. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Some first thoughts:

- Convolution must be done piecewise, because the log kernel will change with wavelength. For instance, convolving with a Gaussian in linear space will require different kernel with different sigmas for each wavelength.
- How do I handle this? Shift the kernel to the desired wavelength, log it, and re-shift back to zero?
- If this is true, that means that a symmetric kernel in linear space will be asymmetric in log space, doesn't it?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions on SO have to relate to special programming problems. So, show what you tried so far by editing the question. Otherwise youre question is offtopic.

Comment: I had the same question. I think it is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624005/how-do-i-perform-a-convolution-in-python-with-a-variable-width-gaussian?rq=1